# como enviar nombre y valor de un boton submit via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy usando el obj. FormData() para enviar los distintos controles de entrada de un formulario pero el problema es que excluye el input submit que envió el formulario, claro que chrome si la hace pero los demas navegadores no. Tengo varios submit s. En la documentacion de la W3C dice que un boton submit de los varios botones submit s solo el que envia el formulario tiene exito pero esto no se cumple con ajax excepto en chrome. en el backend estoy trabajando con PHP y lo que quiero es: que boton submit envió el formulario y asi de esa manera hacer una cosa o otra cosa pero no me llega el boton submit para recoger con la variable global $_POST[''] y vuelvo a repetir esto no pasa en chrome . porfa cual serial la solucion adecuada para este problema .

Comment: sube el codigo que tengas para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Sube tu código para apoyar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar de esta forma:

En los inputs independiente del lenguaje de programación que manejes manda todos los parámetros con el id del campo.

Creas el input con y le agregas el name.

```
<input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" />
```

Creas un botón para mandar todos los parámetros

```
<input id="BotonEnviar" name="BotonEnviar" type="submit" />
```

Luego con jQuery validas si ese botón fue clickeado.

```
$('#boton_cargar').click(function() { });
```

Creas la variable la cual contiene el parámetro que acabas de mandar

```
var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
```

Luego creas el ajax y le pasas el formulario de php + los parámetros

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "GET", 
url: 'resultados.php?nombre='+nombre, 
success: function(data) {
```

si los parametros fueron enviados correctamente ingreso el resultado en un div

```
$('#resultados').html(data); 
$('#resultados div').slideDown(1000); 
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#boton_cargar').click(function() { 

var nombre = $("#nombre").val(); 

$.ajax({ 
type: "GET", 
url: 'resultados.php?nombre='+nombre, 
success: function(data) { 
$('#resultados').html(data); 
$('#resultados div').slideDown(1000); 
} 
}); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" />
```